# how to get the 3d map button in code?

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, uibarbuttonitem, ios7

are there any way to get one 3D button like this:

[image]

what i want to do, is something like this:

```
 MK3dBUTTON *3dButton = [[MK3dBUTTON alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView];
 [3dButton setTarget:self];

UIBarButtonItem *3dbarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:3dButton];
[self.uiTollbar setItems:@[3dbarButton];
```

so how can i take this 3d button directly in code?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeMapViewButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
[button setTitle:@"3D" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:self.view.tintColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:@"3D" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setTitleColor:[self.view.tintColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.15] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:25]];
UIBarButtonItem *changeMapViewItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I tried it with:

```
UIBarButtonItem *changeMapViewItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"3D" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(changeMapViewButtonPressed:)];
[changeMapViewItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:25], NSFontAttributeName,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But then the Text does not align with the icons in the UIToolbar.

HTH
Dominik